# Is there a way to extract the diamagnetic and paramagentic components from NMR output from Gaussian16?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I'd like to be able to split the NMR value in Gaussian16 into its diamagnetic and paramagnetic terms. I'm coming over from ADF, where this can be done easily. Is there a straightforward command to give Gaussian16?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include an example input file, so that contributors have a chance to work on what you are working on; and maybe explain with this example what you expect to get.